# Why does the electricity go off during a thunderstorm?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, lightning

I don't see a convincing reason why electricity should go off during a thunderstorm. I am not talking about a transformer blowing off and causing a permanent power cut, but a temporary one, lasting for a few minutes. I mean, it's not like all the wires are laid on top of buildings so they are prone to getting hit, this happens even if they are not hit. And what's more, they are all well-insulated. What really causes the power cut?

Comment: Surges can still trip the protection devices (think giant breakers) without blowing up a transformer. Some of those devices are self-resetting, so they come back on line in a reasonable time.

Comment: Hi Ambica. This isn't really a physics question. You are more likely to get an answer on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @John Rennie I thought so. Will post it on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time lightning strikes the ground, a huge electrical current surge flows *through the ground* in the vicinity of the strike. If there are any power lines, transformers, or power distribution switchgear in the immediate vicinity of the strike, it is possible for that current surge to upset the equipment even though none of the wires, etc. were directly hit by the lightning. If that happens, there are fuses or automatic circuit breakers which sense the current surge and shut down that portion of the grid to protect the rest of it from damage.

The automatic cutoff is on a timer which attempts to reconnect the power after a delay, usually 10 to 15 seconds, as most of the current surges occur when for example a tree branch is pushed into a wire by a particularly strong gust of wind during the storm. Since such an upset is temporary, after the gust is gone the line is safe again and your power is restored after that delay.

If the reconnection causes another surge, the system cuts it off a second time, waits for a bit, and then tries one more reconnection. If it still fails after three tries, it probably means a line is broken and touching the ground. The system then locks itself off and alerts the grid operators that a serious fault has occurred.

In the case of a blown fuse, a reset requires someone on a lift truck to disconnect the power at a switch in the grid network to render the line safe, and then go up to the fuse on the pole and replace it. This can require between 30 and 45 minutes.